# How to pass data Codeigniter Controller to Angularjs Controller

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, codeigniter

Trying to pass Codeigniter controller response to angularjs CTRL 
**In AngularJs: I did alert(response.data) showing Undefined data is not coming data**

Codeigniter controller code:

```
 function index(){          
    // echo "inside function";
    $data = validate_my_params(array('id' => 'required|id'));
    if($data['status'] == 'success'){    
        $result     =   $this->LowCredit_model->info($data['data']);    
        //print_r($result);    
        jsonSuccess($result,$result['succ_code']);    
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
}
```

From Model i can get the data as printing data is below:

```
Array
(
    [status] => success
    [id] => 7
    [succ_code] => succ_update_1
    [data] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [credit] => 0.00
            [firstName] => Rahul
            [lastName] => Joshi
            [email] => rahul@gdiz.com
        )

)
```

Angular js CTRL code:

```
    $scope.init     =   function() {    
    alert('init');    
        gdiztunnel.post(     
        'order/LowCredit', {    
           id: $configId 
        }    
    ).then(    
            function success (response) {
                response    =   response.data;   
                alert(response.data);    
                if(response.status  ==  'success') {
                    alert('success1');
                    $scope.lowcreditCtrl.data = response.data;    
                    alert($scope.lowcreditCtrl.data);
             }
        }
}
```

Made  **alert(response.data)**  showing **Undefined**

Comment: Use console.log(response.data); to check the result remove alert(response.data); It will show you the result in Browser-> Inspect Element->console check it

Comment: Hi  Boominathan Elango, I Removed i have used console.log(response.data) . Same undefined is showing.

Comment: The Response data is not coming  correctly: function success (response) {
                    response    =   response.data;

                    alert(response.data);

Comment: first check the response  function success (response) {  console.log(response);

Comment: Hi Boominathan Elango, i checked console.log(response); it is coming the these  value ----   Array
(
    [status] => success
    [id] => 7
    [succ_code] => succ_update_1
    [data] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [credit] => 0.00
            [firstName] => Rahul
            [lastName] => Joshi
            [email] => rahul@gdiz.com
        )

)
{"status":"success","id":"7","succ_code":"succ_update_1","data":{"id":"7","credit":"0.00","firstName":"Rahul","lastName":"Joshi","email":"rahul@gdiz.com"},"elapsed_time":""}

Comment: Remove the `print_r($result);` statement

Comment: @Rajkumar remove echo & print_r() from your codeigniter controller then try the console it will works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hide the **print_r($result);** in your controller then check the console

```
      function success(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
     }
```

> Hope this helps